# "git push --mirror" fails to push some refs, are the other refs being pushed correctly?

Tags: git

I'm migrating git repos between two systems and I'm wondering if when a `git push --mirror` fails to push some refs, the other refs are pushed successfully...

For example, I'm receiving an output like this for my git push:

```
   eaa296537..f8ee5c121  master -> master
 - [deleted]             20200619.2.dev
 - [deleted]             20200619.3.dev
 * [new branch]          feature/mailing -> feature/mailing
 * [new tag]             20200626.5.dev -> 20200626.5.dev
 * [new tag]             20200626.6.dev -> 20200626.6.dev
 ! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/11/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system
 ! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/4/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system
 ! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/6/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/TEST'
```

Are the other branches and tags being actually pushed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why is it happening?

Azure also stores information in references(I got the info on  [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/670915/failed-to-push-some-refs-after-using-bfg-despite-h.html)). Azure Repos store information about pull requests in read-only references.

That means that if you just naively git pull --mirror from one GitHub repository, and then try to git push --mirror to Azure repository, then your will get the errors you're showing in your question.

### Solution

You can pull the references that you really need: in particular, the branches (refs/heads), tags (refs/tags) and notes (refs/notes). By selecting only these sets of references, you won't clone the private, read-only references, and you won't try to push them back up to the other repository.

I hope this script may help you on it:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eufo pipefail

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 source_repo_url target_repo_url" >&2
    exit 1
fi

SOURCE_URL="$1"
TARGET_URL="$2"
WORKDIR="$(mktemp -d)"

echo "Cloning from ${SOURCE_URL} into ${WORKDIR}..."

git init --bare "${WORKDIR}"
cd "${WORKDIR}"

git config remote.origin.url "${SOURCE_URL}"
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*'
git config remote.origin.mirror true
git fetch --all

echo ""
echo "Cloned to ${WORKDIR}; pushing to ${TARGET_URL}"

git push --mirror "${TARGET_URL}"

echo ""
echo "Cleaning up temporary directory ${WORKDIR}..."

rm -rf "${WORKDIR}"

echo "Done."
```

Answer based on article: https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/mirroring_git_repositories.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes: the output from `git push` (or `git fetch`, for that matter) shows you wish refs were accepted and which were rejected.

(A Git can always reject some refspecs for whatever reason it likes.  In this case it looks like you are pushing to GitHub, and they reserve all `refs/pull/` names to themselves.  Branch and tag names live in the `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` spaces so this does not block branch or tag updates.)